# GOES Image Viewer - GeoTIFF metadata

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, metadata, noaa, goes-16

I am working with GOES Latest Full Disk Dust RGB product.

I do not want to process this product locally, thus I am downloading the GeoTIFF available in the website (rectangle 2 - attached image).

When I open the GeoTIFF there is no information about the acquisition date inside the metadata, so I am planning to build a web scraper to retrieve the time from rectangle 1 - attached image.

My questions are:

- Why there is no date information inside the GeoTIFF?
- Do you know if I can get blocked by using a web scrapper on https://www.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/goes/fulldisk.php?sat=G16 ?
- Is there a better option for downloading the Dust RGB product without processing locally?

[image]